# How do I repair/recover "RAW" usb drive partition?

Tags: usb, data-recovery, fat32, repair

Something happened to one of my USB drives. When I connect it my computer, Windows thinks that it's "RAW", and asks me to format it. But it should be FAT32, and chock full of files.

- I looked in `diskpart`. It shows the correct size (1TB) but shows the file system as RAW.
- I've tried `chkdsk`, it says `CHKDSK is not available for RAW drives.`
- I've tried using Mac's Disk Utility to repair it, but the Verify and Repair buttons are grayed out.
- I've tried GPartEd in Ubuntu. It fails to identify the filesystem.
- I've tried using ntfsprogs/ntfs-3g in Ubuntu 12. ntfsfix gives up and says `try chkdsk`. chdsk (ms-sys) is unavailable in Ubuntu 12.
- I've tried using fsck, but it doesn't do much. I think it's only for ext partitions.
- I've tried using TestDisk. I answered Y to `Write FAT boot sector, confirm ? (Y/N)`, and it responded: `Write error: Can't write new FAT boot sector`
- I've tried using Recuva. It says `Data error (cyclic redundancy check).`

Comment: You can try a low-level data recovery tool like Recuva. But generally, it's not worth the effort and you should just requalify the drive and reformat it. Recover your data from a backup.

Comment: testdrive or testdisk? I've never heard of testdrive

Comment: @JourneymanGeek My typo, it's "TestDisk". Either way, it fails to work.